# Enabling/Disabling "PageBreakBefore" in Word 2016 using C# +.Net on VSTO addin.

Tags: c#, vsto, ms-office, office-addins, office-2016

Greeting of the day everyone.

I am currently developing an Word 2016 adding using VSTO tools in VS2015. I hit a strange issue.

My requirement is to  enable or disable PageBreakbefore in Word 2016 using a button. I manage to find the code is VB which is `Selection.ParagraphFormat.PageBreakBefore = True` which is simple True/ False thing.

Now, when I try to write the same code in C# .Net, which is `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.ParagraphFormat.PageBreakBefore =  true` It's giving an error.

The error is you can't convert int to bool. When we see the intellisense, it show that the value can be set to **True** or **False**. but if you see it's cast type, it's type of **int** . [image: Intellisense Snapshot]

[image: Error]

Any Help is appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Regards
Aman

Comment: and this is the MSDN page for the above property : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._paragraphformat.pagebreakbefore.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is resolved. Here is the solution .

To Enable PageBearkbefore

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.ParagraphFormat.PageBreakBefore = -1;
```

To Disable PageBreakbefore

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.ParagraphFormat.PageBreakBefore = 0;
```

Thanks. and I do hope that it will save someone else time :)

Regards
Aman